# How to have rounded and rectangular images on the same page

Tags: css

I need one rectangular image to NOT be rounded, and on the same page, have the photos be rounded.

I placed this in the  section of my bootstrap 4 template:

```
<style>
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
```

The photos are fine but the new image 1920px x 20px jpg is distorted (i.e. rounded).

Any suggestions please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to give each image that you want to be round a class

```
<img class="round" src="...">
```

Then in your css you'd

```
.round {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Perfection!!  Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh! Thank you for letting me know. Am new. Your answer and quick response are very much appreciated!!!  :-)